# Example/counterexample of distribution $P$ such that $D(P\parallel Q) <\infty$ where $Q$ is Gaussian, but $E_P[X^2]=\infty$

Tags: entropy

I am looking for an example or a counterexample of a distribution $P$ such that
\begin{align}
D(P\parallel Q) <\infty
\end{align}
where $Q$ is standard Gaussian, but $E[X^2]=\infty$ where $X \sim P$.

A classical example of distribution such that  $E[X^2]=\infty$ is Cauchy. However, for Cauchy $D(P\parallel Q)=\infty$

Comment: This is just a guess and I'd have to apply some elbow grease to make it more than that. Have you considered making $P$ a Student's t-distribution?

Comment: @MichaelHardy No, I haven't considered this. Thank you for this suggestion.